# How to access the variable's new value inside a subquery during update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

In the following example:

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

declare @var int = 10

insert into #temp values(1, 2, 2)
insert into #temp values(2, 4, 4)
insert into #temp values(3, 6, 6)

update T set 
@var = 100,
col2 = @var * col2,         -- here @var yields 100, cool
col3 = (select @var * col3) -- but here it's value will be 10
from #temp T

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

The values of `col2` are multiplied by 100 and the ones from `col3` by 10, as commented. **Why does this happen?**

I need to access the newer value of the variable *inside the subquery*. I'll do this with more complex code, actually in a where clause (something like: `where @var = 4`).

Answer (score 0):

Just use two variables:

```
declare @var2 int = 2;
declare @var4 int = 4;

update T set 
col2 = @var2 * col2,
col3 = @var4 * col3
from #temp T
```

Comment: Actually the only reason why i want to use an variable is that it's value is a result from another subquery (pretty huge by the way). And it's value will be used several times along the update, so i don't want to repeat the subquery that many times

Comment: Could you executed the sub-query once and initialize the variable, then initialize the second variable using the first?

Comment: the subquery uses values of the row which is being updated, so, nope

Comment: Could you show me the whole statement? You can added to the question as `EDIT`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. When you use SELECT @var, it grabs the older version the variable(the 10 value). So I move it outside the select statement and it works perfectly. Try it out:

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 int, col3 int)

declare @var int = 10

insert into #temp values(1, 2, 2)
insert into #temp values(2, 4, 4)
insert into #temp values(3, 6, 6)

update T 
set @var = 100,
col2 = @var * col2,         -- here @var yields 100, cool
col3 = @var * (SELECT col3) --notice @var is outside select clause
from #temp T

select * from #temp

drop table #temp
```

Results:

```
col1        col2        col3
----------------------------
1           200         200
2           400         400
3           600         600
```

Comment: Indeed, but do you have any clue on why?

Comment: It's just the way SQL Server runs the query. When you put the variable in the select statement, it apparently grabs an older version of your variable. Sorry wish I could be more help, but at least it works right?